# How can I implement this animation in Android?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-alertdialog

[image: Anim]

I'm trying to implement this animation. So, I implemented a `Recyclerview`.
On recyclerview item click I'm openning a fullscreen dialog. I tried to implement animation from YoYo animation library, but its not nearly as nice as this. Here's my fullscreen dialog code:

```
private void showDialog() {

        View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.work_rv_details_dialog_layout, null);
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Light);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(dialogView);

        YoYo.with(Techniques.FadeInUp)
                .duration(1500)
                .playOn(dialogView);

        dialog.show();

    }
```

Any help?
Thanks...

Comment: try shared element transition , it will not be exact but you can get some similar effect .

Answer (score 0):

First of all whatever view you want to share from First Activity to Second Activity, add this property in view `android:transitionName="logo"`

For Example ImageView from first Activity

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:transitionName="logo"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp" />
```

The start Second Activity like this

```
 final ImageView imgLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLogo);

            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,Login.class);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(SplashScreen.this, imgLogo, "logo");
                startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
            }else {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Then in second activity again specify same transitionName to respective view

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:transitionName="logo"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

That's it!!!

Comment: So, in the picture, the animation is implemented on an Activity but not a full screen dialog, right?

Comment: Only child view is shared nothing else. remaining all the animation like scaling and all, android do it for itself.